# Is it legal to have a two driver’s licenses if one is from another country?

Tags: united-states, traffic, new-york-state, driving, new-york-city

In the USA, in almost every case, possessing two driver’s licenses from different states (e.g., California and Georgia) is illegal.

I’m wondering about a related situation - is it legal to have two driver’s licenses if one is from another country? In particular, I have a New York license and a New Zealand license, and I’m wondering if I need to destroy the New Zealand one. I maintain residences in both places and travel often (about 10 times per year).

These are ordinary, non-commercial driver’s licenses.

Comment: It's possible to "maintain a residence" somewhere without being a resident there for the purpose of driver licensing.  In which place do you spend more time?

Comment: I sure hope so or I've been doing it wrong for the last 25 years. I have too passports, it's hard to see how 2 licenses are a problem. Actually 3, I have an international one as well.

Comment: @phoog why does it matter in which place I spend more time?

Comment: Normally you are required to convert the DL from your former **main** place of residence when moving to a new main residence. Goal is, if the one DL is revoked, you will not have an alternative DL to use. Problems arise when you don't get a local DL (which is not the case here). Are NY licenses reconised in NZ? Otherwise I don't think any harm will be caused when asking them about it as long as you have (and use) the local one.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter for answering the question about whether you're allowed to have both licenses, but it should have a bearing on which license you would keep if you had to give one up.

Comment: When I moved from WI to TX, TX DMV took my WI license and put a hole in it (literally with a hole punch), and issued me a TX license. 6 years later when I moved back to WI I went to the DMV and they said my license was still valid and just made me a duplicate.

Comment: @RonBeyer I suppose the takeaway from that story is that it varies widely according to the jurisdiction, and that there is no comprehensive national scheme in the US, which would imply that there's no such scheme internationally, either.